# Python - saving the for loop's result

Tags: python, loops, save

```
result = [ ]
cents = [25, 10, 5, 1]
number = 141
for cent in cents:
    if number >= cent:
        helper = number // cent
        number = number - (helper*cent)
        result.append(helper)
print(result)
```

I know this might be an easy question, but how do I save the results in such a way that the program output would be a string (example: "25 * 5, 10 * 1, 5 * 1, 1 * 1") or a list [25 * 5, 10 * 1, 5 * 1, 1 * 1]

Comment: replace `result.append(helper)` with `result.append(f"{cent} * {helper}")` to get a list

Answer (score 1):

Simply change your `append` call to:

`result.append(f'{cent} * {helper}')`

or

`result.append(str(cent) + ' * ' + str(helper))`.